# Is it possible to speed up loading time of Mathematica script?

Tags: scripting

Even a simple

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
(* ::Package:: *)
Print[1]
```

takes 3 seconds to finish on my computer.

Can Mathematica script load only what it needs for executing script? This loading time is so slow and unusable to me as a script language for small job compares to python.

Comment: Do you use the engine? That takes longer to start up for the first time, most certainly for the license check. The engine uses a license that expires every month, and every invocation with an expired license renews the license, and every subsequent launch then happens instantly. So if you use the engine, just try it again, and if it's not the engine, i. e. a locally installed M, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke Thank you for reply. I do not use engine. I am using windows mma, executing `xxx.wls`. No matter how many times I run `xxx.wls`, it always takes 4 seconds.

Comment: Get a *real* operating system then. There are soooooooooo many Linux flavors. It's not on the M side of things. M comes up just fine and fast on a real operating system, I use the scripting functionality several times every day. Try deleting the .Mathematica directory in your user directory (will be re-created), try deleting the accumulated stuff in the temp directory--Win *loves* to accumulate the temp gunk until it is manually deleted, on Linux the temp dir is in RAM, that's must faster and disappears/resets on every boot.

Comment: And the usual on Win: try disabling anti-spy, incremental backup, VPN, ... is scripted M the only thing that launches so slowly? How do other scripts come up?

Comment: @AndreasLauschke What do you mean other scripts? Something like `wolframscript -code 2+2` also takes the same time. Oh, I count the time wrong previously. The script takes about 3 seconds. But still very slow compared to python.

Comment: Other scripts you run in Win. With #!/usr/bin/env you start a script. Run some other script in Win. I don't think I can help you any further on this issue, I'm not a Win person and never will be. I can't imagine this to be a M issue, it works for everyone else and on all Linux distros. And if it's a Win issue it's in the wrong group. Good luck.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke Well, actually I have a linux server. Running mma script is only a little faster, takes about 1.7 seconds. So I am really curious that you say you can execute script instantly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use only a subset of the language (excluding all those symbols defined in top-level code), you may use the undocumented '-runfirst' switch. In Windows:

```
PS C:\Users\Glenn> Measure-Command {math -run '2+2;Exit[]'}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 2
Milliseconds      : 200
Ticks             : 22000335
TotalDays         : 2.54633506944444E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000611120416666667
TotalMinutes      : 0.036667225
TotalSeconds      : 2.2000335
TotalMilliseconds : 2200.0335


PS C:\Users\Glenn> Measure-Command {math -runfirst '2+2;Exit[]'}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 132
Ticks             : 1322163
TotalDays         : 1.53028125E-06
TotalHours        : 3.672675E-05
TotalMinutes      : 0.002203605
TotalSeconds      : 0.1322163
TotalMilliseconds : 132.2163
```

I discovered this while trying to solve the same problem as you. I actually used it to implement a faster script reader. Just remember that using '-runfirst' restricts the language somewhat. I don't think even NIntegrate works at this stage, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow, this is fast! `wolframscript -runfirst "Print[Names[]];Exit[]"` shows a lot of functions, that is great. But unfortunately, it seems that it `-runfirst` does not support script file.

Comment: If you do something like this:

math -noprompt -runfirst '<<script.txt;Exit[]'

Then it works. You just have to manually call Print any time you want a line outputted. I personally found that kind of annoying and spent some time re-implementing Get ('<<') at the top level to print every line automatically. I can share some of my code if you'd find it helpful.

Comment: To be clear, I've added the Mathematica directory to the system PATH variable and I'm invoking math.exe directly, instead of wolframscript.exe, so I'm not sure if things are different that way.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This almost solves my issue. By almost I mean, I do not understand why Mathematica doesn't provide this execution mode explicitly and force us to use undocumented `-runfirst` combined with awkward `<<script;Exit[]` : )